# Save Not working after new field added to already generated scaffold in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say that I add one more field in my model. Then i made changes in my _form page.But when i try to save I am not being able to save the latest field.

Comment: Incomplete information, paste the code of model view controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using rails version above 4, you have to add that field to strong params.

See the last `private` method:

saying `params.require(:foo).permit(:bar, :baz, :new_field)`